# Add headers to a SecureSocket or SecurityContext to WebSocket

Tags: dart, flutter

The WebSocket has the option to add a headers to the request but you can't add a SecurityContext to it. The SecureSocket has the SecurityContext so I can add the ssl certs but can't add headers. Any idea on this?

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to create a websocket with a SecurityContext object
As I don't have access to the underlying HttpClient I've tried to use the
runZoned method

```
 int i = 0;
  socket = await io.HttpOverrides.runZoned<Future<io.WebSocket>>(
  () => io.WebSocket.connect(uri, headers: headers),
  createHttpClient: (io.SecurityContext securityContext) {
    log.w('creating HttpClient ${i++}');
    return new io.HttpClient(context: options.securityContext);
  },
);
```

the createHttpClient is called some 3550 times
and then nothing happens

It should be very simple because the websocket httpclient just lays there

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dcd275fa74ee5cfa86bb115fc67f0ccf6248fd7f/sdk/lib/_http/websocket_impl.dart#L981

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}


// Run this code in main function
HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution would be to pass a `SecureSocket` to create a `WebSocket`.

Example:

```
SecureSocket socket = await SecureSocket.connect("host", port);
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket(socket);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If I do this I can't send headers.

Comment: How are you doing them now?

Comment: the default WebSocket constructor has the option to pass the headers.

Comment: The default constructer does not seem to have it. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html